# Trying to delete comments as they are rendered via Jquery in my Raiks App

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails Recipe Manager project I am working on, now in the process of implementing jquery/ajax to show resources without a page refresh (course requirement, I cannot use remote=true)

So my issue now is with deleting comments, I am able to create comments just fine and delete them as well but only if i refresh the page after creating them. For some reason, my click event cannot be activated unless i refresh. Here is my code:

```
$(function createComment() {
    $("#new_comment").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const values = $(this).serialize()

        $.post(this.action, values).success(function(response) {

            $('div.comments_container').append('<div class="new_comment_' + `${response.id}` + '"> </div>')

            $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<h3 class="cheading">' + ` ${response.user.name}` + ' gives' + ` ${response.rating}` + ' out of 5 stars! </h3>')
            $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<p class="cdescription">' + `${response.description}` + '</p>')
            $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="ecomment" href="/recipes/' + `${response.recipe_id}` + '/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '/edit">Edit</a>' + " ")
            $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="dcomment" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '">Delete</a>')

        });

        $('form#new_comment')[0].reset();

    });
});


$(function deleteComment() {
    $('a.dcomment').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var r = confirm("Delete this comment?");
        if (r == true) {
            $(this).parent().hide("slow");
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

my full repo is at: https://github.com/Bartekswistak/fun_guy_chef/tree/jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element doesn't exist till you click the button and run the function `deleteComment()`, so you can't bind the click event to an element that doesn't exist yet, try this one:

```
$(function deleteComment() {
  $('body').on("click",'a.dcomment', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  var r = confirm("Delete this comment?");
    if (r == true) {
      $(this).parent().hide("slow");
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
  });
});
```

full code:

```
$(function createComment() {
 $("#new_comment").on("submit", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

const values = $(this).serialize()

$.post(this.action, values).success(function(response) {

  $('div.comments_container').append('<div class="new_comment_' + `${response.id}` + '"> </div>')

  $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<h3 class="cheading">' + ` ${response.user.name}` + ' gives' + ` ${response.rating}` + ' out of 5 stars! </h3>')
  $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<p class="cdescription">' + `${response.description}` + '</p>')
  $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="ecomment" href="/recipes/' + `${response.recipe_id}` + '/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '/edit">Edit</a>' + " ")
  $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="dcomment" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '">Delete</a>')

     });

    $('form#new_comment')[0].reset();

     });
});


$(function deleteComment() {
  $('body').on("click",'a.dcomment', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  var r = confirm("Delete this comment?");
    if (r == true) {
      $(this).parent().hide("slow");
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: @BartekSwistak you're welcome. please don't forget to check as answer if it was helpful to you